# Why is the ng-submit not firing the $scope.submit function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have App.js with the following code:

```
var app = angular.module('githubApp', []);
```

and I have githubAppController with the following code:

```
app.controller('githubController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        var promise = $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/odetocode');
        promise.then(onUserGet);

        var onUserGet = function (response) {
            $scope.user = response.data;
        };
    };
});
```

in my page.html, I have the following code:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/App.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/githubController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="githubApp">
    <div ng-controller="githubController">
        <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submit()">
 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

                        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
                        <input type="reset" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset" />
                    </div>
                </div>

        </form>

<div class="col-sm-5">
            <label>{{user.name}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <a ng-href="{{user.blog}}">{{user.company}}</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img ng-src="{{user.avatar_url}}" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Why is the ng-submit not firing the $scope.submit function? Is there something wrong am doing?

```js
var app = angular.module('githubApp', []);
app.controller('githubController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.submit = function() {
    var promise = $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/odetocode');
    promise.then(onUserGet);

    var onUserGet = function(response) {
      $scope.user = response.data;
    };

  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="githubApp">
  <div ng-controller="githubController">
    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

          <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
          <input type="reset" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reset" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <label>{{user.name}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <a ng-href="{{user.blog}}">{{user.company}}</a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img ng-src="{{user.avatar_url}}" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know it's not firing?

Comment: When I click on submit, and debug it in developer tools, it's not breaking on any line of code.

Comment: What if you put some debug logging there?

Comment: You have your files duplicated twice in the question. What for?

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford There is not error in your code. Please check this [http://plnkr.co/edit/5dZzCu3hw1QLqHLF9hhg?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/5dZzCu3hw1QLqHLF9hhg?p=preview). When you hit submit button check your console. There is a rest request made to get data from git api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var promise = $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/odetocode');
promise.then(onUserGet);

var onUserGet = function (response) {
  $scope.user = response.data;
};
```

`onUserGet` is not yet defined at this point. You call it before you define it. This can't work.

So, `submit` **is** triggered (contrary to what you think). But because it's broken, you don't observe the desired side-effects.

Comment: Are you sure, There is issue with function expression. Please check http://plnkr.co/edit/5dZzCu3hw1QLqHLF9hhg?p=preview plunker Check variable hoisting for more detail

Comment: @MohanSingh: oh, I'm very sure. Hoisting is irrelevant here. https://monosnap.com/file/N79syykrbGFv9GTflGcow9UuC68Sij.png

Comment: Only onUserGet is hoisted but it not yet initialized thus undefined and certainly not of type function yet. Sergio is spot on.

Comment: Apart from this issue, get() is not returning anything!

Comment: @UkatJalal: what do you mean? it does for me.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I mean that on my side, response is undefined.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev actually what you said was right, it's a hoisting issue, once I moved the onUserGet to the top it worked, but the question is, why don't I have undefined error in console? Second thing, is it normal to take up to 4-5 seconds to query using $http, while when I paste the url in browser, it takes less than 1 second to get back the json object? I know a lot of questions in this comment, but appreciate the clarification. thanks

Comment: "why don't i have undefined error" - because $http handles this case.

Comment: So how do I troubleshoot it in case I have a function that was undefined as in my case?

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford: debug logging. Sprinkle `console.log` all over.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code.

```
$scope.submit = function() {

        var promise = $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/odetocode');
        promise.then(function(response) {
          $scope.user = response.data;
        });
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan : ok. i will follow thanks for giving guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your controller,

```
var app = angular.module('githubApp', []);
app.controller('githubController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.submit = function () {
        console.log("In function");
        $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/odetocode').success(function(data){
          $scope.user = data;
        })


    };
});
```